# Как можно выбрать и преобразовать файл в base64?

Tags: c#, uwp

Хочу по нажатию кнопки открывать проводник для выбора файла (`FileOpenPicker`) и после этого преобразовывать выбранный файл в `base64`. Никак не получается разобраться как связать тип переменной, который я получаю после выполнения кода:

```
FileOpenPicker open = new FileOpenPicker();
open.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
open.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

// Filter to include a sample subset of file types
open.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

// Open a stream for the selected file
StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

С примером кода base64:

```
var fB = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\rab\kot.jpg");
string encodedFile = Convert.ToBase64String(fB);
Console.WriteLine("Base 64 Encoded File : {0}", encodedFile);

var dFB = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedFile);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\rab\newkot.jpg", dFB);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StorageFile предоставляет информацию о файле. Еще у него есть метод `OpenStreamForReadAsync`, позволяющий открыть файл для чтения (возвращает поток). В итоге можно сделать так:

```
FileOpenPicker open = new FileOpenPicker();
open.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
open.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

// Filter to include a sample subset of file types
open.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

// Open a stream for the selected file
StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync();

var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
var bytes = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);

string encodedFile = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```